# Composer create-project from bitbucket

Tags: git, composer-php, bitbucket

I have a project in my bitbucket repository and I'm a very newbie with composer

In this project I have composer.json with all my require and settings.

I'm trying to install my project directly from my bitbucket repo, what i want to do it's the same things we can do with a github project for example.

For example:

```
composer create-project thelia/thelia-project path/ 2.2.0
```

But if I execute this command:

```
composer create-project vendor/name .--repository-url=https://vendor@bitbucket.org/vendor/name.git
```

the result is:

```
https://vendor@bitbucket.org/vendor/name.git/packages.json could not be downloaded
```

I have already inserted my ssh key on bitbucket for deploy

I committed a packages.json to name.git repository but it doesn't work.

This command obviously is wrong:

```
composer create-project vendor/name . --repository-url=git@bitbucket.org:vendor/name.git
```

the result is:

```
Invalid repository url given. Has to be a .json file or an http url
```

I read somewhere that composer create-project act as git clone and composer install, but I'm not able to let it work in the right way.

What's wrong? 
I found a lot of answer here but I wasn't able to let them works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#create-project):

> --repository-url: Provide a custom repository to search for the package, which will be used instead of packagist. Can be either an HTTP URL pointing to a composer repository, or a path to a local 
>   packages.json file.

This means this parameter can only be used for a replacement of Packagist, not as a pointer to one single package. There is no parameter to do what you want.

However, you don't need to use `create-project`, because all it does is clone the repository, and run `composer install` on it's dependencies. You can do that by hand.

Note that cloning the repository will not change any metadata. You'd still have to do this by hand even if `create-project` had worked. I think this is a flaw in the way how `create-project` currently works, making it less useful.